# How maltiple value using usestate localstorage in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, local-storage

I want to work using  maltiple values in use state and crud in local storage  use state like
const [Data,setData]=[[{
name:'luis',
pass:'1234',
//.......
}]
]

```
And it updates with the form
<input>
```

// .......

```
if value true  Display  take look at this example I try but I cannot do how to solve it
```

import './App.css';
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';

```
function App() {
  const [User, setUser] = useState([
    {
      Name:'',
      Pass:'',
      Email:'',
    }
  ]);

 
  const [storedUser,setstoredUser]=useState([])

  
  const handle = () => {

     localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringfy(...User))
    
     setstoredUser(...User);

  };
  const remove = () => {
     localStorage.removeItem();

  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
         <h1>Name of the user:</h1>
         <input
            placeholder="Name"
            name='Name'
            value={User.Name}
            onChange={(e) => setUser({...User,[e.target.name]:[e.target.value]})}
         />
         <h1>Password of the user:</h1>
         <input
            type="password"
            name="Pass"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={User.Pass}
            onChange={(e) => setUser({...User,[e.target.name]:[e.target.value]})}
         />
           <h1>Email of the user:</h1>
          <input
            type="mail"
            name="Email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={User.Email}
            onChange={(e) => setUser({...User,[e.target.name]:[e.target.value]})}
         />
         <div>
            <button onClick={handle}>Done</button>
         </div>
         {storedUser.Name && (
            <div>
               Name: <p>{localStorage.getItem('Name')}</p>
            </div>
         )}
         {storedUser.Pass && (
            <div>
               Password: <p>{localStorage.getItem('Pass')}</p>
            </div>
         )}
          {storedUser.Email && (
            <div>
               Password: <p>{localStorage.getItem('Email')}</p>
            </div>
         )}
         <div>
            <button onClick={remove}>Remove</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   ); 
}

export default App;
```

Here I try how to do this formate I try to all data in state and stringify set this local storage. then remove and display I think explaine on detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a few things incorrectly here:

- you are not providing a key for local storage
- you don't need to spread objects directly inside setState
- use the removeItem method to clear the user from localStorage
- you are setting the user as an array to state not an object, this is unnecessary in the example you have

If the goal is to persist a single user between sessions via local storage. Then all you need to do is save the user to local storage when the form is submitted.
Then, when the component loads, check local storage for user data.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [User, setUser] = useState({
    Name: '',
    Pass: '',
    Email: '',
  })

  const handle = () => {
    const nextUser = JSON.stringify(User)
    localStorage.setItem('user', nextUser)
  }
  const remove = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('user')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedUser = localStorage.getItem('user')
    if (storedUser) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(storedUser))
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Name of the user:</h1>
      <input
        placeholder="Name"
        name="Name"
        value={User.Name}
        onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...User, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
      />
      <h1>Password of the user:</h1>
      <input
        type="password"
        name="Pass"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={User.Pass}
        onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...User, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
      />
      <h1>Email of the user:</h1>
      <input
        type="mail"
        name="Email"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={User.Email}
        onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...User, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
      />
      <div>
        <button onClick={handle}>Done</button>
      </div>

      {User.Name && (
        <div>
          Name: <p>{User.Name}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {User.Pass && (
        <div>
          Password: <p>{User.Pass}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {User.Email && (
        <div>
          Password: <p>{User.Email}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <button onClick={remove}>Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: why this is not removed button click not instantly remove when  I refresh it, then I found to delete,how to do it I real time

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the key

```
localStorage.setItem("User",JSON.stringfy(...User))
```

If you want each key. Loop over they keys and values and set them. As stated by another user, your UserState is an array where it should just be an object

```
Object.entries(User).forEach(([key,value])=>{
      localStorage.setItem(key,value)
    })
```

Comment: can you give me such an example?

Comment: localStorage.setItem("User",JSON.stringfy(...User)) will create one entry into local storage called "User" and it will contain all the user fields. Iterating through the User will create 3 items in local storage such as "Name", "Pass"  and "Email". So you can can call localStorage.getItem("Name")

Comment: can give me example with key i cannot do it

Comment: your example is good #tia

Answer (score 0):

Since `User` already is an array of user objects I wouldn't spread them in your `handle` function. You also need to set a `key` if you're saving in `localStorage`. This is how to save your list of users under `"users"`:

```
const handle = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringfy(User));
  setstoredUser(User);
};
```

Now when retrieving users from the `localStorage` you can make use of `JSON.parse` like this:

```
users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]");
```

And for deletion you would need the key `"users"` here as well:

```
localStorage.removeItem("users");
```

Comment: can you give well example #TIA